# Android: Spinner setSelection by Tag

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I define BaseAdapter to fill Spinner with records from SQL
I setTag for item in Spinner to equal Record ID in SQL database.

```
public static class Refueling_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context vContext;
    private List<Banziny.Refuel> mRefuelingList;
    //private int mListing;

    public Base_Adapter(Context vContext, List<AppTest.basic> mBaseList) {
        this.vContext = vContext;
        this.mBaseList = mBaseList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBaseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mBaseList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = View.inflate(vContext, R.layout.item_base, null);
            convertView.setTag(mBaseList.get(position).getBase_id());

            TextView Basename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Base_name);
            Basename.setText(mBaseList.get(position).getBase_name());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

As you see I set Tag for spinner item to equal SQL record ID.
Now I just need to know how to setSelected for Spinner using Tag which equals SQL Record ID.

```
int baseidtoselect = mBaseList.get(0).getBase_ID();
```

this id retrieved from database and i need to find tag in spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function

```
public static void selectItemByTag(Spinner spinner, int tag) {
    Refueling_Adapter adapter = (Refueling_Adapter) spinner.getAdapter(); // it is Refueling_Adapter because your Spinner use Refueling_Adapter
    for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position++) {
        if(((YourObjectModel)adapter.getItem(position)).getBase_id() == tag) { // YourObjectModel here is AppTest.basic
            spinner.setSelection(position);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've issue with this ((YourObjectModel)adapter.getItem(position)).getBase_id()

Comment: I've adjust it to my code but the idea seems fine to me. Thanks